# Calculating the spectrum of a specific coordinate ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

So, let $F$ be a field and $b_1,b_2,b_3,t_1^{\pm},t_2^{\pm}$ be formal variables satisfying $t_it_i^{-1}=1$.

Let $I$ be the ideal generated by the equations $b_1+b_3+b_1b_2b_3=t_1^{-1}$ and $1=t_1^{-1}t_2^{-1}$

I need some help figuring out what $\operatorname{Spec} (\frac{F[b_1,b_2,b_3,t_1^{\pm},t_2^{f\pm}]}{I})$ is?

If there is a series flaw inherent in this question, please let me know.

I know that $\operatorname{Spec} (\frac{F[b_1,b_2,b_3,t_1^{\pm},t_2^{f\pm}]}{I})$ is going to be an affine variety. What are the defining equations for this variety? Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'd really appreciate some clarification from one of the legit math Einsteins that I know hang out here... Thanks

---

edit:

If $t_1^{-1}=1$, then we would have:

$b_1+b_3+b_1b_2b_3-1=0$ and $t_2^{-1}=1$.

Just looking at the first equation I see that:

if $b_1=0$ then $b_3=1$ and $b_2$ could be anything.

if $b_3=0$ then $b_1=1$ and $b_2$ could be anything.

if $b_1 \neq 0 \neq b_3$ then $b_2 = (-b1-b3)(b_1^{-1}b_3^{-1})$, and so $b_1$ and $b_3$ can be any invertible invertible element.

This leads me to conclude that $\operatorname{Spec} (\frac{F[b_1,b_2,b_3,t_1^{\pm},t_2^{f\pm}]}{I}) \cong F \amalg F \amalg (F^*)^2$

Why is this incorrect?

Comment: Please use \operatorname{Spec} to format $\operatorname{Spec}$: it produces better spacing than your previous mathjax. I've made the upgrade for you in your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** The answer that was previously here was incorrect. First, the second equation lets you eliminate $t_2$ so we're left with a single equation

$$F[b_1, b_2, b_3, t_1^{\pm 1}]/(b_1 + b_3 + b_1 b_2 b_3 = t_1^{-1}).$$

This single equation just says that $f(b_1, b_2, b_3) = b_1 + b_3 + b_1 b_2 b_3$ must be invertible; equivalently, the above is a localization

$$F[b_1, b_2, b_3][f^{-1}]$$

which geometrically means it corresponds to the open subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^3$ given by the complement of $V(f) = \{ (x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb{A}^3 : x_1 + x_3 + x_1 x_2 x_3 = 0 \}$. Probably more can be said but it depends on what you want to know.

If we set $t_1^{-1} = 1$ then we instead get the closed subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^3$ given by $V(f - 1) = \{ (x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb{A}^3 : x_1 + x_3 + x_1 x_2 x_3 = 1 \}$. Your case analysis is correct but it doesn't imply the disjoint union decomposition you wrote because the three cases are not disconnected; in fact $V(f - 1)$ is irreducible.

Comment: Thanks homey!! Lookin good btw!!

Comment: By the way, what is this fancy $G_m$ you wrote called? A multiplicative group of rank $m$?? A Grassmannian?

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa $\mathbb{A} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$, the multiplicative group scheme. The letter $m$ stands for "multiplicative".

Comment: Thanks. Would this answer change if $t_1=1$?

Comment: @Hakuna: that would kill the $\mathbb{G}_m$ factor.

Comment: Can one of you guys look at my edit and tell me what is wrong with my thinking?

Comment: @Hakuna: whoops, sorry, that is my mistake; I misread your first equation. You can't eliminate $b_1$ like I said; I didn't see the $b_1$ factor in $b_1 b_2 b_3$.

Comment: disclaimer: my knowledge of algebraic geometry is bounded by 15.1 of Dummit and Foote

Can you give me an example of why these three cases are not disconnected? It seems they are pretty mutually exclusive to me. Would it be wrong to say that as a set the affine variety in question is equal to $F \amalg F \amalg (F^*)^2$?

Comment: @Hakuna: the cases are mutually exclusive but they aren't disconnected. For example, working over $\mathbb{C}$, the sequence $(b_1, b_2, b_3) = \left( \frac{1}{n}, 0, 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)$ is a sequence of points in case 3 whose limit is in case 1. And in fact over $\mathbb{C}$ this variety is connected in the Euclidean topology.